# (Typescript/Javascript) setInterval method can't call other functions

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to call the function callMe() every 1000 ms. This works so far, but I cannot call another function out of callMe(). I get the following Error:

> uncaught TypeError: this.sortTargets is not a function

My class variable:

```
private intervalId : any;
```

The code/functions

```
constructor () {
    this.intervalId = setInterval(this.checkLabelConflicts, 1000);
  }

  private sortTargets() {
    console.log("hello world");
  }

  private checkFunction()  {
  this.sortTargets();
}
```

Why am I not able to call other functions out of the intervaled function? I already tried to set the constructor to bottom of the code, it feels like this is a declaration missing error. If someone has another solution without setInterval (e.g. workers/threads?) you're welcome to explain it to me.

Happy monday

Comment: Because `this` is not what you think it is during the callback!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[How to access the correct `this` inside a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

```
constructor () {
    this.intervalId = setInterval(this.checkLabelConflicts.bind(this), 1000);
  }

  private sortTargets() {
    console.log("hello world");
  }

  private checkFunction()  {
  this.sortTargets();
}
```

I had to .bind(this)

Comment: Or you could just use arrow functions